# call c# class method by reflection with constructor using dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net-core, reflection, dependency-injection

```
 var fileName = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}\{2}.dll", Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)),"ProviderDLLS", $"UtilityPayments.Providers.TestProvider");
 if (!File.Exists(fileName)) return null;
 AssemblyName an = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(fileName);
 Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(fileName);
 Type objectType = assembly.GetType("UtilityPayments.Providers.TestProvider.Class1");
 IProviderProcessor remoteAssembly = (IProviderProcessor)Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
 return await remoteAssembly.GetProviderData();
```

I call the class method, which implements `IProviderProcessor` interface using reflection.
if I declare a constructor in `Class1` class  and add interfaces using DI, I get this error:

> System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined
> for type 'UtilityPayments.Providers.TestProvider.Class1'.    at
> System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtorSlow(Boolean publicOnly,
> Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean fillCache)    at
> System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
> Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, Boolean wrapExceptions)
> at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic,
> Boolean wrapExceptions)

`Class1` constructor:

```
public class Class1: IProviderProcessor
{
    private readonly IProviderService _providerService;
    
    public Class1(IProviderService providerService)
    {
        _providerService = providerService;
    }
    
}
```

How can I call `Class1` methods using reflection if I want to inject interfaces in the constructor?
The code works fine if I remove the constructor, but I need to use applications other functionalities in `Class1`, which are implemented using dependency injection.

Comment: Your code doesn't reference a container at all. How would your code know what IServiceProvider to provide to your class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for your help.I solved it using  serviceprovider to get instance of the interfaces which are injected in constructor of the Class1 class.

```
var fileName = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}\{2}.dll", Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)),"ProviderDLLS", $"UtilityPayments.Providers.TestProvider");
if (!File.Exists(fileName)) return null;
AssemblyName an = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(fileName);
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(fileName);
Type objectType = assembly.GetType("UtilityPayments.Providers.TestProvider.Class1");
var constructors = objectType.GetConstructors();
var firstConstrutor = constructors.FirstOrDefault(); //assume we will have only one constructor
var parameters = new List<object>();

foreach (var param in firstConstrutor.GetParameters())
{
   var service = _serviceProvider.GetService(param.ParameterType);//get instance of the class
   parameters.Add(service);
}

IProviderProcessor remoteAssembly = (IProviderProcessor)Activator.CreateInstance(objectType,parameters.ToArray());
return await remoteAssembly.GetProviderData();
```

Comment: This is nice, but DI uses interfaces most of the time, meaning that there can be multiple implementations of the same, or one that is a generic like IOptions<> (and something like that have dependencies that themselves have dependencies). To make this a catch-all, the tail call recursions will be ridiculous, and there might be built-ins that demand to be singletons. This stuff is hard, and I'm trying to figure it out myself with little luck so far

Answer (score 2):

I had to solve this near exact problem.
What i found to be the easiest, maybe not the best, was to use a ServiceProvider.

in whatever class you want to run your code add a ServiceProvider:

`private protected IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;`

You can inject it as normal:

`public YourClass(IServiceProvider services){_serviceProvider = services;}`

then replace:

`IProviderProcessor remoteAssembly = (IProviderProcessor)Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);`

with:

`IProviderProcessor remoteAssembly = (IProviderProcessor)_serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(objectType);`

Comment: thanks, I used  _serviceProvider  to get instance of the ProviderService class

Answer (score 0):

`Activator.CreateInstance` has a prototype that allows you to pass constructor arguments. They need to be contained, in order, within an array of objects, as shown below.

Of course, you'll need to be able to get a reference to a provider service somehow.

```
var providerService = GetProviderServiceFromSomewhere();
var arguments = new object[] { providerService };
IProviderProcessor remoteAssembly = (IProviderProcessor)Activator.CreateInstance(objectType, arguments);
```

Comment: thanks, I used  _serviceProvider  to get instances of the DI classes and passed it as  array .